# Incorrect data being returned from IMPORTXML in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

**EDIT:** It looks like my issue is that Google is querying from the US when I want Australian data. I'm now looking for a way to scrape sites using IMPORTXML in a way that the site recognises as coming from Australia.

---

I am using the Google Sheets IMPORTXML function to scrape a collectibles website for price data on their top Digimon cards. I can see clearly on the page that the value of the first card is $129.99 AUD, but when I query the page, I get different values.
Here's the import function I'm using:

```
IMPORTXML("https://www.cherrycollectables.com.au/collections/digimon-singles","(//div[@class='productitem--info'])")
```

At the moment, this first card is showing a value of $99 on my spreadsheet, but on other days I've seen $100 and $124 with no change being shown on the web page - it has stayed at $129.99.

In Chrome's Network logger I can see that the URL is correct; a GET request is being made to this URL to generate the page. The response XML includes the values as they appear on the page, so I don't think the DOM is being edited (which would explain different values).

Additionally, changing to any other currency (I've had issues with Google being based in the US vs me in AU) doesn't line up with the values being returned either.

**Image of HTML as it appears on the page**

[image: Image of HTML as it appears on the page]

**Image of correct dollar value in the GET response**

[image: Image of correct dollar value in the GET response]

**Image of incorrect dollar value appearing on my spreadsheet**

[image: Image of incorrect dollar value appearing on my spreadsheet]

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://au.4everproxy.com/direct/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuY2hlcnJ5Y29sbGVjdGFibGVzLmNvbS5hdS9jb2xsZWN0aW9ucy9kaWdpbW9uLXNpbmdsZXM-",
 "(//div[@class='productitem--info'])")
```

[image: 1]

[image]

Comment: A proxy to make the query from an Australian server to get Australian prices, perfect. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When I view the source code, I can see that the price in the HTML is hardcoded as $99.00 for the first card. I also see that the code includes scripts that convert that amount on screen depending on what is chosen in the currency dropdown for the page. Google Sheets can only read the HTML; it has no way to account for active scripts.

Of note, when I choose 'AUD' from the currency dropdown (I am located in the USA), it shows the hardcoded price of $99.00 followed by 'USD' and not 'AUD'. This also indicates that what you *see* on the site is based on scripts that may be detecting location and, in some respects, mixing things up.

Comment: Thanks for the response! If it's hard coded then it would make sense for sure. Where in the sources are you seeing this? 
It's also strange to me that the number would vary day-to-day if it is hard coded.

Comment: The behind-the-scenes number won't change, but the scripts representing the current value of that number WOULD change the displayed value often. Right click anywhere that isn't a link on the site and choose "View source code" (at least in Chrome, though it's likely similar in other browsers).

Comment: I've had a look at this myself, and the value there is 129.99, just like what's shown on the page. It's looking more and more like this is a location issue. If you're in the US and you're seeing the same numbers as Google but I'm seeing something different, then it may be something I can't resolve using Google Sheets.
I've had a similar issue in the past, and I never found a way to get Google to query from Australia.

Comment: If we are both seeing different numbers in the same spot in the HTML, then scripts are still responsible; they are just writing the HTML "on the fly." And Google Sheets can't scrape where scripts are involved. However, when I paste your posted formula exactly to a sheet, the information that is retrieved is exactly what is shown on the website when AUD is selected.